# How do I populate the rest of the id tags with data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need help. Currently, my `<p>` tag has an id="test". I am trying to populate all the p tags with the variable *originalString*. However, only the first `<p>` tag is shown to contain data. --> see image for Reference [See Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKgqF.png).

How do I populate the rest of the p tags with data.

```
            <script>
                var originalString = ${entity.getGenreSolr()};
                var genreList = document.getElementById('test');
                genreList.innerHTML = originalString;       
            </script>

            <div class = "Option_Title_summary_rating">
            <c:out value="Rating of Anime: ${entity.getRatingsSolr()} / 10 " /><br/>
            <div class = "Option_Title_summary_summary">
            <p id="test"></p>
            </div>
```

Comment: `id` literally means `identity`, so logically speaking there can be only one element with a given `id` although technically it is possible to have multiple elements with the same `id`. But `document.getElementById` will only give you the first. You could try using `class` attribute instead with the `document.getElementsByClassName()` element collection

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var originalString = ${entity.getGenreSolr()};
    $("#test").text(originalString);      
</script>

 <div class = "Option_Title_summary_rating">
     <c:out value="Rating of Anime: ${entity.getRatingsSolr()} / 10 "  /> <br/>
     <div class = "Option_Title_summary_summary">
         <p id="test"></p>
     </div>
</div>
```